# Eclipse plugin refresh after properties change

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an eclipse plugin based on GEF. When I change the properties, I need to close all files and open them manually.
How can I refresh the instances of my plugin after changing properties?

```java
public class MyPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {   
    public MyPreferencePage() {
        super(GRID);
    }

    public void createFieldEditors() {
        addField(new StringFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.MY_CONF,
            "Label", getFieldEditorParent()));
    }

    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        setPreferenceStoreMyEditorPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performOk() {
        boolean res = super.performOk();
        // Validated input
        // I think I have to refresh the config here
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change what sort of properties? Using what API?

Comment: I change the plugin properties via an IWorkbenchPreferencePage.

Comment: So are you storing the value in the plugin preferences? Show us the code that is saving the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to your preference store which will be told about changes to preferences using:

```java
MyEditorPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
```

where `listener` is an implementation of `org.eclipse.jface.util.IPropertyChangeListener`. The single method in this interface is

```java
 public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
 {
    String changedPropertyId = event.getProperty();

    // TODO check if you need to do something for the changed property
 }
```

Comment: That's not my problem. My problem is that after I changed the properties all file currently opened with my editor are still in the old state.

Comment: So your editor will have to listen for this property change and do whatever it has to do to update.